# Stripe payment ssl protocol error WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We have used stripe payment using PHP. It works on the local machine but in live server, it's not worked as expected. We shared the code which we used and also attached the screenshot of the error. Not sure where we made the mistake, can you guide us?

Stripe Code :

```
require_once('Stripe.php');

Stripe::setApiKey('secret key');

echo '<form action="" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="publish key"
          data-description="Access for a year"
          data-amount="5000"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
</form>';

if($_POST) {
 $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';

}
```

Local Machine

[image: Local Machine output result]

Live Server

[image: Live Server error report]

Answer (score 0):

1) It looks like potentially you haven't copied the `data` folder that comes with the stripe php bindings over to your server --- this contains the `ca-certificates.crt` file referenced in the `failed loading cafile` error. Make sure this folder is present on your server and see if that resolves the issue!

2) If you continue to have trouble the issue may involve an inability of your server to communicate over TLS 1.2 to Stripe. From your syntax it looks like you are using an older version of Stripe's PHP library so you'll want to use the second sample here to [test that](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#php).

You can also run a test script [like this](https://gist.github.com/olivierbellone/9f93efe9bd68de33e9b3a3afbd3835cf) to help determine your libcurl and openssl versions, if curl is able to make TLS 1.2 connections in the first place. If you need to upgrade curl and openssl some helpful advice is [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-openssl-to-support-tls-1-2). You can also chat with your sysadmin or web host on the matter.